# how to focus empty combobox

Tags: java, swing, focus, jcombobox

in my project, i have a empty combobox which i want to populate after clicking on it.

```
comboCurrent = new JComboBox<String>();     
comboCurrent.setBounds(265, 181, 80, 20);
add(comboCurrent);
comboCurrent.setEditable(true);
comboCurrent.setSelectedItem(null); 
comboCurrent.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO populate here
        System.out.println(e);
    }
});
```

but somehow the action listener does not work here.
is there a way to listen to the first click on the combobox while it is still empty?

Comment: `comboCurrent.setBounds(265, 181, 80, 20);`  Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), along with layout padding & borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556).  (Perhaps you should give the combo a `Default Text`..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ActionListener` invokes only when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. For first clicking I recommend  you to use [`FocusListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html) or [`MouseListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) on your `JComboBox`.

Comment: `FocusListener` would be better, since a `MouseListener` would not fire if the user tabs to the combo.